# What is the best practice for removing padding in nested Bootstrap .col's with a parent of .container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**The Context**

I believe the following to be true:

- Bootstrap 4 adds left and right padding to `.col`.
- `.row` does not have padding, but if there are `col`'s inside it they do.
- `.container` has left and right padding. And it's nested `col` do as well.

The example below results in nested padding.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this example results in no padding.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Goal**

I need my parent container to have padding, but everything in it to **not** have exterior left and right padding.

If .row > .col > .row is the official Bootstrap solution to removing interior padding (but without parent container having padding) - then what is the best practice to achieve it WITH exterior padding for the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the no gutter class to the 'row'.

.no-gutters

Detailed here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Also columns should almost always be inside a row so you should add another row before your first column.